# Is it possible to realign polylines from KMZ in Google Earth?

Tags: google-earth

I have a street network that has been extracted from AutoCAD DWG's and converted to a KMZ file. The resulting polylines, when launched in Google Earth, do not visually align with the imagery.

I am not sure what the source data is, and not really concerned with anything other than realignment (transformation?). I have ArcExplorer but no other GIS at the moment other than AutoCAD and Microstation, which aren't true GIS platforms.

Apologies for the rambling, post, thanks.

Comment: does you DWG layer have any projection or spatial reference info?

Answer (score 2):

If you look at the data in Google Earth, right-click a feature and choose properties:

[image]

Then, while the properties dialog is open, you are in an editing mode. The cursor will change and let you move points of the feature:

[image]

The one caution is that I don't think it keeps connectivity to adjacent features, so don't move end points if you want to keep a topological network.

This is - of course - all assuming the lines are only slightly off, and that you want to edit them manually into position. If they are a large distance away then consider that the original coordinate system was somehow wrong, or if they are all a consistent distance away then maybe they need an offset?

Answer (score 0):

You could try offsetting all of the lines by a fixed distance, and through trial and error match them up.

I've had a similar problem using ArcGIS and KML. My solution was to figure out what the offset error was and shift everything by that amount.